# First Party use of Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel Passport for API authentication,

This is my stack:

- `ReactJs (front-end)`
- `Laravel (backend - API)`

Currently I'm giving Personal Access Tokens directly to users like this, and after getting the token user's can access protected routes as usual:

```php
    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate(); // it authenticate the user based on $request->email and $request->password
        
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = Auth::user();
        $token = $user->createToken('auth');

        return response([
            'message' => 'success',
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token->accessToken,
        ]);
    }
```

It works fine but the problem is now, anyone can get their token directly using tools like Postman, and use that token to access protected routes. which I don't want.

I only want the users to access the routes via my whitelisted frontends. like `Reactjs SPA` etc..

I read some articles sugesting to whitelist our domains on `config/cors.php`, it works for modern browsers, but still tools like postman would work. :(

Is there any-way I can acheive this?

Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript you can check that part of the docs. I think you can protect your api with that middleware solution

Comment: I read that but still I don't understand how do I use that? as the Middleware it asking to put on the `web` routes, but I want to use the `api` routes.